# Make Telegram bot to read only /commands as administrator

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I am using Telegram bot API with AWS Lambda and Zappa.

Everything was working fine. Until I realised that bot's webhook is being called everytime whenever a message is sent by anyone in the group.

I want to limit this webhook requests, as Lambda allows for only 1 million calls which is sufficient if bot is invoked, but only when `/commands` are called.

As I have to pin and edit messages using bot, that's why administrator permission is must.

I just want my bot to respond only to `/commands` along with administrator rights.

Please help me in tackling this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you added your bot to a Telegram group. In this case, the first thing that you need is group id. This should help: https://github.com/GabrielRF/telegram-id#web-group-id

And then you need to write a function that identifies the status of a chat member. You can do this using [getChatMember](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmember) method in Telegram Bots API.
If the chat member's status is "creator" or "administrator" then the response is sent to that user.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things you need to do.

1. `setPrivacy` for your bot - go to `BotFather` chat and use the `/setPrivacy` command which gives you the ability to set:

> 'Enable' - your bot will only receive messages that either start with
> the '/' symbol or mention the bot by username. (Should be default)

> 'Disable' - your bot
> will receive all messages that people send to groups. Current status
> is: DISABLED.

2. When [setting the commands for the bot](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setmycommands), set the `BotCommandScopeAllChatAdministrators` [scope](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#botcommandscopeallchatadministrators) which should limit the use of the command only to the admins of the chat.